# BASH replace two variables in order with loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have two files with this structure:

File1.txt:

```
1,,
1,,
1,,
1,,
1,,
1,,
1,,
1,,
2,,
2,,
2,,
2,,
2,,
2,,
3,,
3,,
3,,
3,,
4,,
4,,
4,,
4,,
4,,
5,,
5,,
5,,
5,,
```

File2.txt:

```
0015
0016
0017
0018
0019
```

I want to replace File1.txt numbers with File2.txt in order, so it would look like this:

```
0015,,
0015,,
0015,,
0015,,
0015,,
0015,,
0015,,
0015,,
0016,,
0016,,
0016,,
0016,,
0016,,
0016,,
0017,,
0017,,
0017,,
0017,,
0018,,
0018,,
0018,,
0018,,
0018,,
0019,,
0019,,
0019,,
0019,,
```

And I haven't found an effective loop to do so, any help will be appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

With GNU sed and bash (process substitution):

```
sed -n -f <(sed -n "s|^\([^,]\)\(.*\)$|\1{h;s/[0-9]*/\&\2/p;g}|p" File1.txt) File2.txt > File_new.txt
```

See: `man sed` and `info sed`

Comment: That's great!! is there any way to keep the changes in File1.txt? (I ask this because File1 actually has many columns in csv format)

Comment: This runs a new sed process for every line of the input file.  It would be more efficient to do it in shell, or even to start up perl.

Answer (score 0):

Read the 2nd file into a linear array.  Use it as a lookup table, index by the first field of the 1st file.  With non-numeric keys, use an associative array instead.

```
readarray -t mapping < File2.txt  # -t strips trailing newlines

while IFS=  read -r l;
    do pref=${l%%,*};
    printf '%s%s\n' "${mapping[pref-1]}" ",${l#*,}"
done < File1.txt
```

Or `"${l#[0-9]}"`, or whatever other way will be most future-proof for getting the part of the line you aren't replacing.

Or `shopt -s extglob` and `"${l#+([0-9])}"` (extglob version of the regex `[0-9]+`)

This is pure-bash, no external commands.  If the input files are potentially large, the same algorithm in perl would probably be faster.  bash isn't great for speed.